# Need help to optimze code , cant decide to use dataframe for sorting or mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I am writing code to get data from 1m database (size can increase). I have mysql server locally and writing everything in python. not good at it and trying to optimize everything.

First question is if I can write better sql query and second question is, if I should try to do everything using mysql or it will be good if I use dataframe for example for sorting and filtering data

```
def listJE(company_id, page_num, per_page):
    columns = 'tr_id, ' + 'tr_date, ' + 'description, '  + 'dr_acc, ' + 
              'cr_acc, ' + 'amount, ' + 'currency, '  + 'document, ' + 'comment'

    sn = (page_num - 1) * per_page
    en = per_page
    ncon = myDB()
    query = """SELECT {} 
               FROM transactions 
               WHERE company_id = {} and deleted = 0 
               ORDER BY tr_id 
               DESC LIMIT {}, {}""".format(
            columns, company_id, sn, en)

    df = ncon.getDF(query) 

return df
```

Comment: If you can organize, filter and sort the data using the database, you **must** (not should, MUST) have the database do it for you. Database is for dealing with data and that means sorting, filtering, searching, limiting the results etc.

Comment: Thanks, I am very very newbie with all this and wanted also to measure how normal result is. for example for getting 1 million record from database I need something like 5 seconds as I use several WHERE condition. was digging into forums and there was said to use CASE clause , is small sql query I have there bad or needs improvement?

Comment: If you're really trying to optimize, since it doesn't look like your column list is changing, you could hard code the columns into the query rather than performing 8 concatenations

Comment: Thanks, will do that as well.

Comment: Also someone suggested that using ORM could help but I am more worried about performance and what you think about that?

Comment: MySQL default installation is shipped with config that uses very little RAM. That's why your query is slow. There's no way you can transfer 1 million records to python (or even C) and expect it to deal with data sorting / ordering faster than the database would.

Comment: Well, that makes sense and my mind set to do so. At some level sorting with dataframe gave difference and was wondering why is that and you answer made all clear. thanks. later on will be transfering everything to a server so I guess there will be better performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case, I would suggest using MySQL to do the sorting and return the records you need. Pandas is an amazing tool and can do a lot, but it might not be the best for you in this case.

Since you seem to be limiting the number of rows from a 1 million+ record table, it's likely more efficient to have MySQL sort through it and give you the records you need rather than package up the entire table, transfer it to your application, and then leave it to you to figure out the best way to sort through it and slice the appropriate records.

If you are running the query many times (as your pagination seems to imply), MySQL can cache the query result [see this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44266/does-mysql-cache-queries). So on the next iteration, it might just go "oh, I have this alredy!" and send you the result rather than recomputing it.

Optimization is very nice to have, but consider the cost in time and readability. If you can save some time and make things more readable for the future, like hard coding your column names in the query rather than concatenating them, the go ahead and do it. If you're worried about shaving a few miliseconds off between MySQL or processing in python, you should consider the value gained.

If you are creating a site that has low traffic, then a 5 sec query might be annoying, but it might not be critical. But as was sugested in the comments, running it locally on a workstation might not be a good indication of when you ultimately push it to the server.